# Sort by frequency and value using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following array:

```
var arr = new[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 4 };
```

Now I want to sort this array by frequency:

- The subset of numbers having frequency is 1 [4]
- The subset of numbers having frequency 2 is [1,2]

Then we sort each subset of elements having the same frequency in natural order, resulting in [1,3,4,2,2]

For that  I have written following linq query but I am stuck

```
var line in arr.GroupBy(n => n)
            // Order by the frequency of each group of numbers
            .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
            // Then by the natural order of each number
            .ThenBy(g => g.Key)
            .??
```

Comment: Wait why can't you sort by Count then take that result and expand it to your result array.

Comment: I am no moderator here, but I found you a one-liner answer from an easy google search to another StackOverflow question. Try to do some research. I mean you do have a hugh StackOverflow reputation after all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. You can sort by `group.Count`, as Ya Weng mentioned, and then use `SelectMany` to project the result to the array you need.

You can simplify the operation as well by omitting the `Select` step (as `GroupBy` already projects it to a grouping for you):

```
var arr = new[] { 3, 1, 2, 2, 4 };

var result = arr.GroupBy(n => n)
                // Order by the frequency of each group of numbers
                .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
                // Then by the natural order of each number
                .ThenBy(g => g.Key)
                // Project the groups back to a flat array
                .SelectMany(g => g);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", result));
// => 1,3,4,2,2
```

Here's a fiddle to try: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y3vOi7

Comment: I am expecting 1,3,4,2,2

Comment: @santoshsingh See my edit.

Comment: Why are you using `.Repeat` versus just using the items in `group`?

Comment: Here you don't really need to group nor to repeat... it's a simple order by frequency: always better the simplest linq expression.... (especially for light orm)

Comment: D'oh, you're right. I simplified it.

Answer (score 4):

You can group the numbers by the times they are repeated, sort the groups and sort the elements of each group:

```
var result = arr.GroupBy(n => arr.Count(i => i == n))
                .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
                .SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => x));
```

or

```
var result = arr.GroupBy(n => n)
                .OrderBy(g => g.Count())
                .ThenBy(g => g.Key)
                .SelectMany(g => g);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple like that

```
var res = arr.OrderBy(n=> 
                   arr.Count(x => x == n) )  .ThenBy (n => n);
```

Just order by frequency (then by natural order), nothing more

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ query syntax.

```
var ret = string.Join(",", from n in new[] { 3, 1, 2, 2, 4}
                           group n by n into x
                           orderby x.Count(), x.Key
                           from i in x
                           select i);
// ret = "1,3,4,2,2"
```